# Android app published fail

Tags: android, google-play

I have published Android app the error is

> You uploaded an APK that is signed with a key that is also used to
>   sign APKs that are delivered to users.Because you are enrolled in App
>   Signing, you should sign your APK with a new key before you upload it.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Use a different key, exactly like the error message says?

Answer (score 0):

As the Sign of an app is unique(unless you are releasing update to an existing app).
 So, you need to create a new key, and sign your app with it.